# iPhone SDK - CALayer crash

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am having a big problem figuring out where my app crash is being caused, and I'm not sure how to interpret the crash report.

The crash clearly occurs in Thread 0, but at what step might it actually be crashing in? I certainly am not manipulating CALayers in my code at all. In anyone experience, does this happen for any particular reason?

```
Incident Identifier: 23D06670-4C44-49F4-A0CB-01CF95D558D2
CrashReporter Key:   1d7775167d5336b2369c148ce37405638a6abe74
Hardware Model:      iPhone3,1
Process:         CrazyTimes [3169]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/41DF0A05-710D-48BB-A468-73B7B224F5A3/CrazyTimes.app/CrazyTimes
Identifier:      CrazyTimes
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2012-02-09 18:22:36.422 -0500
OS Version:      iPhone OS 5.0 (9A334)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Codes: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x00600ad0
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x383a7fca objc_msgSend + 30
1   CrazyTimes                      0x00114460 0x1000 + 1127520
2   CrazyTimes                      0x000c2f10 0x1000 + 794384
3   UIKit                           0x331b0f72 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) drawLayer:inContext:] + 270
4   QuartzCore                      0x328c0e16 -[CALayer drawInContext:] + 110
5   QuartzCore                      0x328c0418 CABackingStoreUpdate_ + 1776
6   QuartzCore                      0x328bfc16 CA::Layer::display_() + 966
7   QuartzCore                      0x328bf832 CA::Layer::display() + 122
8   QuartzCore                      0x328bf774 CA::Layer::display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 168
9   QuartzCore                      0x328bf11c CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 228
10  QuartzCore                      0x328bee50 CA::Transaction::commit() + 308
11  QuartzCore                      0x328b6d7e CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 50
12  CoreFoundation                  0x311dcb44 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 12
13  CoreFoundation                  0x311dad80 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 252
14  CoreFoundation                  0x311db0da __CFRunLoopRun + 754
15  CoreFoundation                  0x3115e4d6 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 294
16  CoreFoundation                  0x3115e39e CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
17  GraphicsServices                0x33d8cfe6 GSEventRunModal + 150
18  UIKit                           0x331d073c UIApplicationMain + 1084
19  CrazyTimes                      0x00004084 0x1000 + 12420
20  CrazyTimes                      0x00003af8 0x1000 + 11000

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x324dd3b4 kevent + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x32c31e78 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 708
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x32c31b96 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 30

Thread 2 name:  WebThread
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x324dd010 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x324dd206 mach_msg + 50
2   CoreFoundation                  0x311dc41c __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 120
3   CoreFoundation                  0x311db154 __CFRunLoopRun + 876
4   CoreFoundation                  0x3115e4d6 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 294
5   CoreFoundation                  0x3115e39e CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
6   WebCore                         0x379f2128 _ZL12RunWebThreadPv + 396
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x369a5c16 _pthread_start + 314
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x369a5ad0 thread_start + 0

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x324edcd4 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x369a030a _pthread_wqthread + 610
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x369a009c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 4 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x324dd010 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x324dd206 mach_msg + 50
2   CoreFoundation                  0x311dc41c __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 120
3   CoreFoundation                  0x311db154 __CFRunLoopRun + 876
4   CoreFoundation                  0x3115e4d6 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 294
5   CoreFoundation                  0x3115e39e CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
6   Foundation                      0x3821abc2 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 302
7   Foundation                      0x3821aa8a -[NSThread main] + 66
8   Foundation                      0x382ae59a __NSThread__main__ + 1042
9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x369a5c16 _pthread_start + 314
10  libsystem_c.dylib               0x369a5ad0 thread_start + 0

Thread 5 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x324ed570 __select + 20
1   CoreFoundation                  0x311e066a __CFSocketManager + 726
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x369a5c16 _pthread_start + 314
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x369a5ad0 thread_start + 0

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x324edcd4 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x369a030a _pthread_wqthread + 610
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x369a009c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 7 name:  WebCore: CFNetwork Loader
Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x324dd010 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x324dd206 mach_msg + 50
2   CoreFoundation                  0x311dc41c __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 120
3   CoreFoundation                  0x311db154 __CFRunLoopRun + 876
4   CoreFoundation                  0x3115e4d6 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 294
5   CoreFoundation                  0x3115e39e CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
6   WebCore                         0x37a1b69e _ZN7WebCoreL15runLoaderThreadEPv + 122
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x369a5c16 _pthread_start + 314
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x369a5ad0 thread_start + 0

Thread 8 name:  WebCore: LocalStorage
Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x324ed068 __psynch_cvwait + 24
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x369a5f2e _pthread_cond_wait + 634
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x369a5caa pthread_cond_wait + 34
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x3768940e WTF::ThreadCondition::timedWait(WTF::Mutex&, double) + 54
4   WebCore                         0x37b51494 WTF::PassOwnPtr<WebCore::LocalStorageTask> WTF::MessageQueue<WebCore::LocalStorageTask>::waitForMessageFilteredWithTimeout<bool ()(WebCore::LocalStorageTask*)>(WTF::MessageQueueWaitResult&, bool (&)(WebCore::LocalStorageTask*), double) + 52
5   WebCore                         0x37b5144a WebCore::LocalStorageThread::threadEntryPointCallback(void*) + 106
6   libsystem_c.dylib               0x369a5c16 _pthread_start + 314
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x369a5ad0 thread_start + 0

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x324dd010 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x324dd206 mach_msg + 50
2   CoreFoundation                  0x311dc41c __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 120
3   CoreFoundation                  0x311db154 __CFRunLoopRun + 876
4   CoreFoundation                  0x3115e4d6 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 294
5   CoreFoundation                  0x311db474 CFRunLoopRun + 92
6   CrazyTimes                      0x00039ee4 0x1000 + 233188
7   Foundation                      0x3821aa8a -[NSThread main] + 66
8   Foundation                      0x382ae59a __NSThread__main__ + 1042
9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x369a5c16 _pthread_start + 314
10  libsystem_c.dylib               0x369a5ad0 thread_start + 0

Thread 10 name:  com.apple.coremedia.player.async
Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x324ed068 __psynch_cvwait + 24
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x369a5f2e _pthread_cond_wait + 634
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x369a5caa pthread_cond_wait + 34
3   CoreMedia                       0x3255d000 FigSemaphoreWaitRelative + 212
4   MediaToolbox                    0x3261afca fpa_AsyncMovieControlThread + 18
5   CoreMedia                       0x3257cbc6 figThreadMain + 146
6   libsystem_c.dylib               0x369a5c16 _pthread_start + 314
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x369a5ad0 thread_start + 0

Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x324edcd4 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x369a030a _pthread_wqthread + 610
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x369a009c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0x09b99000    r1: 0x345621e3      r2: 0x0019e7dc      r3: 0x0019e910
    r4: 0x0019e800    r5: 0x09b99000      r6: 0x00199f3c      r7: 0x2fdfdb00
    r8: 0x00196f94    r9: 0x00118870     r10: 0x00196bdc     r11: 0x0019789c
    ip: 0x0019e8f4    sp: 0x2fdfdae0      lr: 0x00114467      pc: 0x383a7fca
  cpsr: 0x20080030
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UIViews` are implemented with `CALayers`, so if you are using UIKit, you are using layers. My guess is that an already released object is receiving messages. Maybe you released an object more times than you should. Try recompiling with `NSZombieEnabled`.

Answer (score 0):

`3   UIKit                           0x331b0f72 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) drawLayer:inContext:] + 270`

By any chance, did you release an objectA which is a delegate to objectB without removing the delegate assignment first, i.e. `objectB.delegate = nil; [objectA release];`?